# Two-way binding to a "custom" RichEditBox's custom properties in ViewModel (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

In UWP apps, the RichEditBox control doesn't work well on its own with MVVM-based design patterns when you need to pass text to/from it in the ViewModel, so I created a custom version of it.

In the custom RichEditBox I have a custom DependencyProperty called Text. My goal is simply to two-way bind that property to a string property located in my ViewModel. That way I can use the string in my ViewModel to set/get text in my custom RichEditBox. This works with ease if I take the XAML-approach. How can this be done in my code-behind file, though? I tried and failed to pull it off. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have some code to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the custom RichEditBox I have a custom DependencyProperty called Text. My goal is simply to two-way bind that property to a string property located in my ViewModel. That way I can use the string in my ViewModel to set/get text in my custom RichEditBox.

For your scenario you could extend a `CustomText` property for your custom `RichEditBox`. As you know you can get or set string for `RichEditBox` by `Document.SetText` and `Document.GetText` method. And then you could listen the text change of `RichEditBox` by 
`TextChanged` event. I have created a `CustomRichEditBox` with two-way binding CustomText property. Please reference the following code.

```
public string CustomText
  {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
      set
      {
          SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value);
      }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("CustomText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomRichEditBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCustomTextChanged)));

  private static void OnCustomTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      CustomRichEditBox rich = d as CustomRichEditBox;
      if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
        {
            rich.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, e.NewValue.ToString());
        }
  }
```

Monitor the changes of `RichEditBox` text dynamically modify the `View-model`.

```
public CustomRichEditBox()
{
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(RichEditBox);
    this.TextChanged += CustomRichEditBox_TextChanged;
}

private void CustomRichEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    this.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out value);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return;
    }
    CustomText = value;
}
```

If you want to bind ViewModel to the control from your code-behind file you could reference the following code.

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
 myBinding.Source = this.DataContext;
 myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Info");
 myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyEditBox, CustomRichEditBox.CustomTextProperty, myBinding);
```

I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/CustomRichEditTextBoxTest.git) to github. Please check.

Comment: Sorry I'm late getting back to the replies. Thanks. However, I think you missed my point. I'm trying to bind to the control from my code-behind file, as stated in the post... I made it clear that binding via XAML was no problem to do. Thanks again!

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is also working pretty well if you binding ViewModel  to the control from code behind. Is that you except?